# Core Data - Particular column update for all records

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I  have developed an iOS app with core date.I am having the below table.

```
 id  | title        | Value
===========================
  1  | Foo          | 100
  2  | Bar          | 200
  3  | FooFoo       | 300
```

Now i want to update the value column of all records to be 500.

I am using below code,

```
NSArray *mutableFetchResult = [[[self.managedObjectContext     executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];
 if (mutableFetchResult == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch result error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
for (NSManagedObject *ob2 in mutableFetchResult) 
{
    [newContact setValue:@“500” forKey:@"Value"]; 
     if (![context save:&error]) { 
            NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
    }
}
```

It works fine.But i don’t want to use for loop to update the records.In my concern i have around 60000 records.So it looks little bit strange.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 you can use `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to do a batch request. I'm afraid, you will have to iterate through every record to update in `iOS 7`.

Read about Batch update in this beautiful tutorial :

[Batch Update in Core Data](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am using  NSBatchUpdateRequest.But is there any other alternate for iOS6&7?.